# Replace \N with NULL with sed in mysqldumped CSV file

Tags: mysql, sed, null

Using mysqldump gives \N instead of NULL for null values.

I am trying to fix this with sed but can not get it to work.

This is what I am trying to do:

In my exported csv file i want to replace any occurence of

```
,\N
```

with

```
,NULL
```

I have tried different variations of this:

```
sed -i -e 's/",\N/,NULL/g' test.csv
```

But can not get it to work. Thanks for all help!

Comment: `sed -i 's/",\\N/,NULL/g' test.csv`?

Comment: That worked great, Wiktor. Thanks a lot for helping!! (I am a bit unsure how to set this as "solved" here).

Comment: Please agree with the duplicate status. Matching backslashes is a long solved issue.

Comment: Yes, I see that my question is a duplicate. Am I expected to do anything further? Thanks for yout patience.

Comment: No, it is fine now.